# Query para trazer 1 registro pai e nele pode conter vários registros filhos (performance)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, query

> Supondo que para o cliente posso ainda colocar mais `joins` como não apenas as vendas, e no resultado dessa consulta trazer bem mais registros. Esse é um jeito performático de se trabalhar ou seria melhor eu realizar consulta a cada tabela separada e ir populando meu objeto Cliente no C#?

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE 
(
    ID_CLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    NOME_CLIENTE VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NOME_CLIENTE) VALUES ('TESTE 1')

CREATE TABLE VENDA
(
    ID_VENDA INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    ID_CLIENTE INT NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE VENDA ADD CONSTRAINT PK_VENDA_CLIENTE PRIMARY KEY (ID_VENDA, ID_CLIENTE)

INSERT INTO CLIENTE (ID_CLIENTE) VALUES ((SELECT ID_CLIENTE FROM CLIENTE WHERE NOME_CLIENTE = 'TESTE 1'))

CREATE TABLE PRODUTO
(
    ID_PRODUTO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    NOME_PRODUTO VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    VALOR_PRODUTO DECIMAL(10,4) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO PRODUTO (NOME_PRODUTO, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ('TOMATE', 10)
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (NOME_PRODUTO, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ('ABACAXI', 20)
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (NOME_PRODUTO, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ('UVA', 30)
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (NOME_PRODUTO, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ('MORANGO', 40)
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (NOME_PRODUTO, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ('ALFACE', 50)

CREATE TABLE VENDAPRODUTO
(
    ID_VENDA INT NOT NULL,
    ID_PRODUTO INT NOT NULL,
    QUANTIDADE INT NOT NULL,
    VALOR_PRODUTO INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO VENDAPRODUTO (ID_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ((SELECT ID_PRODUTO FROM PRODUTO WHERE NOME_PRODUTO = 'TOMATE'), 1, 10)
INSERT INTO VENDAPRODUTO (ID_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ((SELECT ID_PRODUTO FROM PRODUTO WHERE NOME_PRODUTO = 'ABACAXI'), 2, 20)
INSERT INTO VENDAPRODUTO (ID_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ((SELECT ID_PRODUTO FROM PRODUTO WHERE NOME_PRODUTO = 'UVA'), 7, 30)
INSERT INTO VENDAPRODUTO (ID_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ((SELECT ID_PRODUTO FROM PRODUTO WHERE NOME_PRODUTO = 'MORANGO'), 4, 40)
INSERT INTO VENDAPRODUTO (ID_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, VALOR_PRODUTO) VALUES ((SELECT ID_PRODUTO FROM PRODUTO WHERE NOME_PRODUTO = 'ALFACE'), 2, 50)

SELECT CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE,
      CLIENTE.NOME_CLIENTE,
      VENDAPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO,
      PRODUTO.NOME_PRODUTO,
      VENDAPRODUTO.QUANTIDADE,
      VENDAPRODUTO.VALOR_PRODUTO
 FROM CLIENTE CLIENTE
 LEFT JOIN VENDA VENDA ON VENDA.ID_CLIENTE = CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE
 LEFT JOIN VENDAPRODUTO VENDAPRODUTO ON VENDAPRODUTO.ID_VENDA = VENDA.ID_VENDA 
 LEFT JOIN PRODUTO PRODUTO ON PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO = VENDAPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
WHERE CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE = 1
```

> Resultado

```
/* 

ID_CLIENTE | NOME_CLIENTE | ID_PRODUTO | NOME_PRODUTO | QUANTIDADE | VALOR_PRODUTO
1          | TESTE 1      | 1          | TOMATE       | 1          | 10
1          | TESTE 1      | 2          | ABACAXI      | 2          | 20
1          | TESTE 1      | 3          | UVA          | 7          | 30
1          | TESTE 1      | 4          | MORANGO      | 4          | 40
1          | TESTE 1      | 5          | ALFACE       | 2          | 50

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Nicola!

Quando o volume de dados é muito grande e eu tenho a possibilidade de reduzir o volume de dados que terei que manipular, eu utilizo CTEs(Common Table Expressions).

Eu crio uma ou mais CTEs com intervalos de dados, já filtrados pelas condições que quero(intervalo de datas ou o código de um produto, por exemplo).

As CTEs trabalham como tabelas em memória e elas existem apenas na execução da sua query. Elas não são criadas no TEMPDB, igual a uma tabela temporária, o que ajuda na performance. A diferença básica dela pra uma tabela temporária é impossibilidade de executar UPDATES, DELETES e INSERTS, o que não parece ser problema pra sua situação.
Depois de ter CTEs filtradas, eu faço join entre elas e filtro algo mais que seja necessário e faço agrupamentos.

A documentação da utilização de CTEs está nesse [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), recomendo que você dê uma olhada.

Quanto a parte de agrupar no C#, eu não recomendo, você transportaria muitos dados entre o banco e aplicação. O ideal é já retornar seu resultset ideal do SQL e só exibir na sua aplicação.

Na empresa na qual trabalho como DEV, nós temos views e até procedures que são chamadas com o [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper)(um ORM simples e rápido, utilizamos ele apenas pra relatórios. É o ORM utilizado aqui no StackOverflow) e o resultset é renderizado na tela do usuário.

Aqui também tem um [passo a passo](https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/sql-server-como-criar-consultas-recursivas-com-a-cte-common-table-expressions/) legal de utilização das CTEs, no blog do Dirceu Resende (MVP Microsoft na área de Dados).

Espero ter ajudado!